# @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") is throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on this ASP.NET MVC project. I did not do any changes to the _Layout.cshtml or BundleConfig.cs or Web.config. When I ran the project, it is showing the below exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> [External Code] ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in _Layout.cshtml

I tried the minification method but still it failed. If it is possible to view, please check the photos below.

Can somebody help me resolve this issue, please?

[Picture01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx7kZ.jpg)

[Picture02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i7JL.jpg)

[Pciture03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLm8O.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the code in ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml?

Comment: Could you try to remove ```@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")```?

Comment: Same here after updating Nuget packages for a Web API project couple years old.

Answer (score 11):

Replace the following:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mybundle").Include(
            "~/Scripts/...",
            "~/Scripts/..."));
```

with this:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/mybundle").Include(
            "~/Scripts/...",
            "~/Scripts/..."));
```

Comment: could you please explain why this works, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In the method `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles` I replaced all existing instantiation of `ScriptBundle` to instances of `Bundle` and it worked as expected.

Comment: This prevents any of your scripts from being minified....my understanding anyway.  So make sure you are including minified versions.

Comment: Since I only had the problem with the bootstrap bundle, I only updated it for bootstrap, and it worked.  Thank you very much.  I was about to start pulling out my hair.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here with an older Web API project after upgrading all NuGet packages, specifically to Bootstrap 5.1

The same happens on **a new default Web API project** in VS 2019 *after* upgrading its packages to Bootstrap 5.1 - NullReferenceException in _Layout.cshtml!

Apparently dependencies for Bootstrap 5.1 are not yet handled propery by ASP.NET projects -
Downgrading (via VS Nuget Manager) to **the last available 4.x version** solved the issue for my projects.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solution provided by Akanksha resolved the originally described problem after I upgraded an older ASP.NET WebAPI project from Bootstrap 3.x to 5.1.x

In the method `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles` I replaced all existing instantiation of `ScriptBundle` to instances of `Bundle` and it worked as expected.

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Comment: So why add a new answer that is identical to an existing one? What values does this add?